# PHP extending exception

Tags: php, exception

In the following code sample I am trying to get the class name Volvo to show up in the exception message, but instead what appears is CarException. How can I go about getting the class name Volvo appearing in the exception message without specifying `__CLASS__` when throwing the exception?

```
    class Volvo extends Car {
        public function smash() {
            throw new CarException("This car doesn't really smash.");
        }
    }

    abstract class Car {
        public function __construct() {
            var_dump(get_called_class());
        }
    }

    class CarException extends \Exception {
        public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
            $message = get_called_class() . ": $message";
            parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        }
    }

    $volvo = new Volvo();
    try {
        $volvo->smash();
    } catch (CarException $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for [`getTrace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php):

```
class CarException extends \Exception {
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        $trace = $this->getTrace();
        $cls = $trace[0]['class'];
        $message = $cls . ": $message";
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
}
```

`get_called_class` doesn't apply here: it returns the name of the class that "owns" the code, not the one that "called" it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to get the calling class name in the CarException constructor? Like, it works when instantiating Volvo in main (it prints out volvo) but not in the CarException.

Comment: nice! works great! Will delve into it a bit more in regards to getTrace(). I'm guessing the Trace stacks messages up from top down.